# JSON to TSV in scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, shapeless

Is there some elegant way to convert the json data(based on case class) to tsv form?

I have a case class that has nested case class and nested case class can have list and map.

```
case class Product (
  pname: Option[String],
  pid: Int,
  pDetail: Option[PDetail]
)

case class PDetail (
  pbatchNo: List[Int]
)
```

example json:

```
{
  "pname" : "pnameValue",
  "pid" : "pidValue",
  "pDetail":
  {
  "pbatchNo" : [1,2] 
   }
}
```

I want a output like:

pnameValue  pidValue    1    2

Comment: Parse the json to the case class using some json library. Transform the case class to a row. Do that for all.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the toString method and separate the field by tab \t.
Something like:

```
override def toString: String = {
    s"pnameValue:$pnameValue\tpidValue:$pidValue"
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't override `toString` but rather provide a new method.

Comment: You could even override the `apply` in a companion object if you're feeling particularly evil...